# How can I create a Slide Navigation Menu Programatically in Swift using xib files?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create something like this:
[image]

I know I have to use Container View in swift but I don't know how to go about it. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked through CocoaPods? External libraries typically take care of a big chunk of code.

Comment: @CloakedEddy yes I have looked at all the libraries on net, but I want to build my own using xib files.All those libraries have storyboards which I don't use at all

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) library. It's a good starting point. You can use it in your project or take a look at the sources and implement something similar yourself.

Comment: yes I looked at SWRevealViewController. Hmm, I am trying to implement my own navigation menu but just need a guide or something which I can follow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about xibs, but if you want to do it yourself, the best tutorial I've found is on raywenderlich.com (they have all sorts of fantastic tutorials). Here's the [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift). There are a bunch of other tutorials out there that use some sort of "TransitionManager" class that implements the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning and UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocols to get the job done, but it's a bit messier than the approach used in the Ray Wenderlich tutorial, which does indeed revolve around a container view.